# Need help with my Smart Bin Project

Tags: breadboard

Hi I'm doing an individual project based on a Smart Bin, 
My main objective for this project is to prevent bins from overflowing,to detect if bins are nearly full by using an Infrared distance sensor and to alert a person (sending a text message) if bins are almost full while tracking its location.
The equipment that I'm using for this project is a raspberry pi (base), GSM Module: Huawei E220 (sending text message to your phone), GPS Module: RPI Customized GPS Add-On V2.0 Module For Raspberry Pi (Track the location of the bin) and an Infrared Distance Sensor (detecting if the bin is nearly full), The infrared distance sensor has an analog output so I'm using a Analog to digital converter - MCP3002 
I have connect the GSM Module to the Pi, the GPS Module to the Pi, I was suppose connect the analog to digital converter and the Infrared Distance Sensor to the breadboard by following this link:http://raspberry.io/projects/view/reading-from-a-mcp3002-analog-to-digital-converter/#step1
Through this link I have to substitute the potentiometer in the example for the Infrared Distance Sensor but the problem is I can't connect the Infrared Distance Sensor to the Breadboard because of the end the three cables wire, my question is how do I connect the Infrared Distance Sensor to the breadboard?
This is what I've done for my project so far through these images

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site Richard. Unfortunately your question ('How do I attach pins to wires?') is non-Pi specific and as such is [off topic here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might get some mileage from the [Electrical Engineering board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=header+pins+wire), which has several hundred questions on header pins and wires.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to buy male Dupont pins and crimp them to the wires of your sensor:

[image]

Alternatively, you can attach/solder your sensor to a suitable connector (or three separate jumper wires) which you can then plug into the breadboard.

Comment: does this link http://www.instructables.com/id/Fitting-Dupont-Connectors/ explains how to do it, for me I'm just a beginner is it possible to get someone to do it for me e.g. at a store

Comment: Are these are the ones that I should buy from the store https://littlebirdelectronics.com.au/products/0-1-2-54mm-crimp-connector-housing-1x1-pin-25-pack

Comment: @Richard Yep, that link looks OK (I wouldn't cut the insulation in a conical shape, nor I would solder the crimped wires, just cut straight and crimp). 3 pins could be fitted in a reasonable time without the crimping tool (using pliers), but for beginners it is highly recommended to get the right tool which is much easier to use. Another tool which helps a lot is insulation remover (wire stripper), but again, 3 wires could be stripped with a small knife after some practice.